# How to show initially hidden DIV with GWT?

Tags: gwt, html, show

I have a DIV tag which I can made either

```
display: none;
```

or

```
visibility: hidden;
```

Then I want to show it with GWT.

But when I am trying to do

```
RootPanel.get("myid").setVisible(true);
```

or

```
RootPanel.get("myid").setVisible(false);
```

and it has no effect.

I saw in Firebug, that thess functions add "display: none" or remove it in turn. Since there is one explicit "display: none" hardcoded, the DIV is constantly hidden.

So, how can I accomlish the task? Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your JSP

```
<div id="myid" style="display:none ; width:100%">
```

In your GWT EntryPoint class

```
DOM.getElementById("myid").getStyle().setDisplay(Display.BLOCK);
```